# IDependencyResolver interface implementation in F# Web API

Tags: dependency-injection, f#, c#-to-f#

I am re-writing a C# ASP.NET Web API application in F#. I have Models and Controllers done and I moved onto `MyDependencyResolver` that implements [`IDependencyResolver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dependencies.idependencyresolver(v=vs.118).aspx).

I am having a problem implementing the [`GetService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969069(v=vs.118).aspx) method, whose signature in C# is:

```cs
object GetService(System.Type serviceType)
```

So I need to return an `obj` and take a `System.Type` as a parameter.

This is what I have so far in F#:

```
type MyDependencyResolver() =
    interface System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver with
        member this.BeginScope() : IDependencyScope =
            this :> IDependencyScope

        member this.GetService(serviceType:Type) : obj =

            if (serviceType = typeof<Controllers.HomeController>) then
                let homeController = new Controllers.HomeController(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
                homeController :> obj
            // ???
            elif (serviceType = typeof<_>) then
                null           

        member this.GetServices (serviceType: Type) :IEnumerable<obj> =
            let x = new List<obj>()
            x :> IEnumerable<obj>

        member this.Dispose() =
            ()
```

So if `serviceType` is of type `HomeController` I want to return an instance of `HomeController`, and if it's of any other type I want to return null. How do I do that in F#?

Edit:

`GetService` method in C#:

```cs
 public object GetService(Type serviceType)
 {
    if (serviceType == typeof(Controllers.HomeController)){
        return new Controllers.HomeController(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Comment: How did you handle this in your C# implementation?

Comment: Unless you're doing this as some sort of masochistic exercise to learn F#, you should be aware of two things: **1.** There are plenty of DI Containers out there that can do that job, and more. **2.** [Don't use `IDependencyResolver` for Web API; use `IHttpControllerActivator` instead](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/09/28/DependencyInjectionandLifetimeManagementwithASP.NETWebAPI). That's also easy to do from F#.

Comment: @MarkSeemann ;) I am just trying to determine whether our project solution is suitable for to-F# migration.

Comment: Perhaps you'll find this useful, then: http://blog.tamizhvendan.in/blog/2015/04/02/step-10-refactoring-composition-root

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `Activator.CreateInstance(serviceType)` but where do you get the constructor arguments from?

In my projects I use [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx), which is configured as follows:

```
let private ConfigureUnity (config : HttpConfiguration) =
        let rec unityResolver (container : IUnityContainer) =
            { new IDependencyResolver with
                member this.BeginScope() =
                    unityResolver(container.CreateChildContainer()) :> IDependencyScope
                member this.GetService serviceType =
                    try container.Resolve(serviceType) with
                        | :? ResolutionFailedException -> null
                member this.GetServices serviceType = 
                    try container.ResolveAll(serviceType) with
                        | :? ResolutionFailedException -> Seq.empty
                member this.Dispose() = container.Dispose()
            }

        config.DependencyResolver <- (new UnityContainer())
            .RegisterType<IFoo, FooImplementation>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
            .RegisterType<IBar, BarImplementation>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager())
            |> unityResolver
```

Classes (such as your controllers) are then resolved automatically and Unity will create dependencies (the constructor arguments) for you. Using other dependency injection frameworks should be straightforward.

Comment: Is `IFoo` and `FooImplementation` equivalent to `arg1`in my code sample? (In my code sample I get constructor arguments from the same module, they are `ILogger` etc.)

Comment: Yes, these are used by the DI framework (here: Unity) when constructing the object graph. Might be, that some of the arguments have dependencies themselves, which are then resolved too.